# S3 Cloud formation Fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I am working with CF and s3 access. Instead of giving full access, The intenion is to give only partial access to specific bucket's. An example CF code looks like this (below). Apparently policy looks fine , I even ran IAM policy simulator and it run's fine (gives the impression of working as intended). My integration tests even works as well for the bucket. But when I deploy, it fails and gives the HeadObject Operation error. **don't understand why**
I did read previous posted similar question but got no help.

```
Policy:
    - PolicyName: s3-directory-access
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Action: s3:*
            Resource:
              - !Join [
                  "",
                  [
                    "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_1.",
                     !Ref "AWS::AccountId",
                    ,
                  ],
                ]
              - !Join [
                  "",
                  [
                    "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_1.",
                     !Ref "AWS::AccountId",
                  ],
                  ,"/*"
                ]
```

Comment: Is that your actual policy? If not, add yours. What error code/message do you get? What operation are you invoking that results in this error? Also, your bucket name appears to have your AWS account number embedded in it - I assume that is what you meant to do, but just calling attention to it in case you think the account number is a standard part of an S3 ARN (it's not).

Comment: Also, use !Sub rather than !Join: `!Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::bucket_1.${AWS::AccountId}/*'`